# Ember-leaflet how to interact with layers from an other view

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, leaflet

I am just implementing ember-leaflet and I ran into one problem.
I would like to create a list of marks and polylines which I have on my map. Then I would like to handle those layers by interacting the list.

So for example when I click on a list item which coresponding to polyline item, I would like to call `editing.enable()` on the polyline layer. I am using ember-data to render marks and polylines btw..

Some thoughts? I am quite new to ember, I don't want a complete code, just guide me please what I should make in order to make it working and in 'the ember way' :)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to add ids to your layers, and then you can use `layers.findBy('id', id)` in your list action.

```
<a {{action 'enablePolyline' layerId}}>{{layerName}}</a>
```

Create your action in the list views controller, and that controller should use `needs` to access the controller with the layers. From there use `find` or `findBy` to get the correct layer and make any modifications, like `editing.enable()`.

```
actions: {
  enablePolyline(id) {
    if (!id) {
      return;
    }

    let layers = this.get('layers');
    let layer = layers.findBy('id', id);

    if (layer) {
      // do what you need to do with layer..
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've needed ;) Thank you

Comment: I just wanna mention that I had to use ```this.set('controller.polylineLayers', this._childLayers[1]._childLayers)``` in the mapView to set the polylineLayers in my controller as the controller has no 'layers' method.